# Multiple count statement in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been struggling with a multiple count statement

```
select distinct tam.sol_id||'|'||(select sol.sol_desc from sol where sol.sol_id=tam.sol_id)||'|'||count(*)||'|'||sum(org_tran_amt)
||'|'||count(case when ott.tran_date between '01-02-2021' and '24-02-2021' then 1 else 0 end)
from ott,tam
where tam.acid=ott.acid
and tam.gl_sub_head_code in ('85300','85320','85330','85340','85350','85360','85365','85370','85380','85390','85395')
and tran_date <= '24-02-2021'
and ott.del_flg='N'
and acct_cls_flg ='N' 
and tam.sol_id in (select sst.sol_id from sst where sst.set_id='ROFPZ')
and not exists (select * from tct where tct.tran_date=ott.tran_date and trim(tct.tran_id)=trim(ott.tran_id)
and nvl(ott.org_tran_amt-tct.AMT_OFFSET,0)='0' and tct.entity_cre_flg='Y' and tct.del_flg='N')
) group by tam.sol_id;
```

Output of query is as below:

```
834|DH|1|2354|1
835|JA|3|4500|3
833|KO|4|3400|4
```

the output is incorrect, as last column count has to be less than second column count.

Comment: You forgot to change from count to sum, 0 is still counted as 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `count`, you count all the `not null` values, no matter whether they are `1`, `0` or whatever.
For example, this

```
SQL> select count(a), sum(a), count(b), sum(b)
  2  from
  3  (
  4      select 1    as a, null as b from dual union all
  5      select null as a, null as b from dual union all
  6      select 0    as a, 0    as b from dual
  7  );
```

gives

```
  COUNT(A)     SUM(A)   COUNT(B)     SUM(B)
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1          1          0
```

If your `case` gives `1` or `0`, you should better use `sum` instead of `count`.
Another way is to edit your `case` to return `null` instead of `0`, in this way `count` will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite hard to follow.  And whatever problems you have are mostly impossible to understand without sample data and desired results.  I'll get to the one obvious problem in a moment.  But first:

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` format.

It is long past time to use standard `JOIN` format.  `JOIN`s have been part of the SQL standard for *decades*.

One obvious problem in your code is:

```
count(case when ott.tran_date between '01-02-2021' and '24-02-2021' then 1 else 0 end)
```

First, I would fix the date formats to use standard YYYY-MM-DD formats.  More importantly, though, you want `SUM()` not `COUNT()`:

```
sum(case when ott.tran_date between date '2021-02-01' and date '2021-02-24' then 1 else 0 end)
```

`COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values of an expression (or column).  `0` is just as `NOT NULL` as `1` is, so the `CASE` does nothing with `COUNT()`.